# Internal Server Error When I try to access admin url (home page is working)

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am working on .htaccess file and frontend is woking fine . But when I try to access admin it give me internal server error. It is a custome mvc framework.

Here is my .htacess file

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

Options -Indexes

Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -MultiViews
ErrorDocument 404 /sitemap.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^vividtron.demolocation.com [NC]

RewriteRule ^index.htm$ /index.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^all-category.htm$ /all-category.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^brands.htm$ /brands.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^search.htm$ /search.php [NC]

RewriteRule ^([_-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /sub-category.php?furl=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^customer-service.htm$ /customer-service.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^([_-a-zA-Z0-9]+).htm$    /static-page.php?furl=$1 [NC] 
RewriteRule ^offer/([_-a-zA-Z0-9]+).htm$    /special-offer.php?furl=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^pages/([_-a-zA-Z0-9]+).htm$    /popup-pages.php?furl=$1 [NC]

#RewriteRule ^category/([_-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /product-listing.php?surl=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^category/([_-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /featured-product.php?surl=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^brand/([_-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /product-series.php?burl=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^series/([_-a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([_-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /model-listing.php?burl=$1&surl=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^product/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /product-detail.php?furl=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([._-a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([_-a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([_-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /pro-detail.php?url=$1&proId=$2&bid=$3 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([._-a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([_-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /pro-detail.php?url=$1&proId=$2 [NC]
```

Thanks is advance. Please look into file why url http://vividtron.demolocation.com/admin/login.php is not working

Comment: /admin/login.php has nothing to do with RewriteRules.... Its a file not a Rewrited url.

Comment: Please consider adding a few `RewriteCond`s and probably a liberal sprinkling of `[L]` flags, I can't even begin to comprehend that set of rules.

Comment: I guess, the rewrite module is not enabled in Apache’s configuration settings.

Comment: I suggest turning display_errors on in your php.ini. I believe you will see your problem then.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried different hosts? One of my scripts ALWAYS showed me an Internal Server Error, but when I switched hosts, it worked flawlessly.